# How can I untokenize a replaced spacy.tokens.token.Token?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, spacy

I was trying to replace the location name from a string and replace it with any city from the list mentioned below, randomly and the get the new formed string and append it to a file. I tried using spacy for this. I can easily detect the cities and replace the token, but I am stuck with appending them to get the new line.

```
from pprint import pprint
import spacy
import random

list = ['Delhi','Mumbai','Bangalore','Agra','Jaipur','Noida','Lucknow','Bombay','Jaipur','Indore','Chandigarh','Guwahati','Ghaziabad','Faridabad',
        'Pune','Chennai','kolkata','Hyderabad','Goa']

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

sentence = '''Can You deliver pizza to London.'''

entities = nlp(sentence)

pprint([(X, X.ent_iob_, X.ent_type_) for X in entities])
newstr=""
for X in entities:
    newstr += X
    if  X.ent_type_=='GPE' and X.ent_iob_=='B':
        X = random.choice(list)
        print(X)
        #print(type(X))
    elif X.ent_type_=='GPE' and X.ent_iob_=='I':
        X= ' '



pprint(newstr)
```

i am getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shahi\PycharmProjects\pythonscrappingproject\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    newstr += X
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "spacy.tokens.token.Token") to str
```

When i try to run this with commenting out - newstr += X ; it runs okay.

Answer (score 2):

First, do not use the built-in `list` as a variable name, use `l`, for example:

```py
l = ['Delhi','Mumbai','Bangalore','Agra','Jaipur','Noida','Lucknow','Bombay','Jaipur','Indore','Chandigarh','Guwahati','Ghaziabad','Faridabad',
        'Pune','Chennai','kolkata','Hyderabad','Goa']
```

Then, you can use

```py
for X in entities:
    if  X.ent_type_=='GPE' and X.ent_iob_=='B':
        newstr += random.choice(l) + X.whitespace_
    else:
        newstr += X.text + X.whitespace_
```

where `X.text` is the actual token text and `X.whitespace_` is the whitespace after that token in the original char sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Try typecasting the `spacy.tokens.token.Token` to `str` by writing `newstr += str(X)`.

Comment: no as of now , you mean - 
`new_x= str(X)` 
`new_str +=new_x` ?

Comment: There is no need to cast to `str`, because each token has the `text` property.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @VarunKumar Are you sure it worked? You force whitespaces while you should not. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68179759/3832970) for a solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the above solution is just a hack. It works. Yours is a better solution.